# Before 1800, were there major schools of Islamic thought that relaxed behavior rules for women on the Hajj?

Tags: religion, cultural-history, islam, women, islamic-history

It is my understanding that most comprehensive works of Islamic thought (past and present) do the following:

- (a) Give rules or guidelines for behavior, some of them specific to women;
- (b) Give rules or guidelines for behavior of pilgrims on the Hajj.

I am interested in the interaction of (a) and (b) before 1800: Did any major works (or connected sets of works or documented attitudes) of Islamic thought promulgate rules or guidelines for women's behavior that might be different for women making the Hajj?

If so, can you point me to any (primary or secondary) sources that focus on this?

Comment: What is the context of this question ? Can you precise which rules you have in mind ?

Comment: The context is mostly personal interest; I am also looking for fictional/nonfictional narrative accounts of women on the Hajj doing unusual things.

Comment: As for the precise rules, I'm not sure. I guess I'm looking for schools of thought that a. Interpreted the Qur'an/Sunnah/etc as promulgating certain rules/guidelines for women's behavior, but b. thought of some of those rules as being relaxed/more flexible for women on the Hajj. So the precise rules would depend on the school of thought. Does that make sense?

Comment: It would start to make sense, if you add some links, e.g. to what you define as "schools of thought"? We need a little bit more of your prior research on this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my last edit I reduced my reliance on the term "schools of  thought" and I think I need to eliminate it entirely. It's a vague term and is better off being replaced by "major works" and some stuff in parentheses. I've done very little prior research other than reading wikipedia articles about the four classical schools of Sunni jurisprudence and survey articles about behavior codes for women within Islam. I heard "somewhere" that some Islamic writings make exceptions of some kind to some of these behavior codes to accommodate the realities of life on the road.